# read file with ip range and see if supplied IP matches any range in file

Tags: php

I am trying to read a file with ip/mask ranges and if the supplied IP matches any range in the file it will return with TRUE or similar function. Here is the code I have below

```
function myip2long($ip) {  
   if (is_numeric($ip)) {  
       return sprintf("%u", floatval($ip));  
   } else {  
       return sprintf("%u", floatval(ip2long($ip)));  
   }  
}

function ipfilter($ip) {  
   $match = 0;  

   $ip_addr = decbin(myip2long($ip));  

   if (file_get_contents('./countryip/all-zones/us.zone')) {  
       $source = file('./countryip/all-zones/us.zone');  

       foreach ($source as $line) {  

           $network = explode("/", $line);  
           $net_addr = decbin(myip2long($network[0]));  
           $cidr = $network[1];  

           if (substr($net_addr, 0, $cidr) == substr($ip_addr, 0, $cidr)) {  
               $match = 1;  
               break;  
           }  
       }  
   }  
   return $match;  
} 

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  

if (ipfilter($user_ip) == 1)  echo "<br />allowed! Your IP is a United States IP!";  
else echo "deny!";
```

An example file (like the one in the example above) is available here
http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/us.zone

Not sure if the code above is correct, I got it from here'
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#86793

Comment: P.S. I tried with a US IP and it echoed allowed, then I tried with a foreign IP (United Kingdom) and it still said allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should add some debug code, just to understand what is going on.

Just like this:

```
if (substr($net_addr, 0, $cidr) == substr($ip_addr, 0, $cidr)) {  
   echo "My IP: $ip\n";
   echo "IP to check: $network[0]\n";
   echo "CIDR: $cidr\n"
   echo "ip digits, my: $ip_addr, check: $net_addr\n";
   $match = 1;  
   break;  
}
```

So you'll see what is going wrong.

Comment: http://kryptodesigns.com/forum/forum.php
Hmm. Well My IP and the IP to check are not matching. :\

I removed the IF conditional as nothing was getting echo'd.

Comment: if nothing is echoed then there is no match, you should receive 0 as return value. And without conditional there is no sense -- you'll match anything like US IP.

Comment: So any idea why my code posted above would not work with the IP list file (us.zone) and a valid US IP such as 74.138.175.137?

Comment: Seems that the list is incorrect.

Look at the list -- there is no 74.138.x.x subnet there.

So there is no match.

Comment: Probably subnet calculator would be usefull, when checking IP in subnet:
http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/SubnetCalculator.jsp